# stream_socket_enable_crypto(); Disables stream_set_timeout

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, timeout, blocking

I have created an xmpp server, first using non tls which works as I want with no errors. The hole authentication works and I can chat with no problems.

Before I start reading from the socket I did:

```
stream_set_timeout($sock, 0, 1000);
```

This will let me do things within the time when there is no new data from the server.

Now I implemented starttls.
I did

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto($sock, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_SERVER);
```

which negotates the tls for me. This didn't worked because the read timeout occured and the tls negotation failed.

I changed the above **stream_socket_enable_crypto** to

```
stream_set_timeout($sock, 30, 0);
stream_socket_enable_crypto($sock, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_SERVER);
stream_set_timeout($sock, 0, 1000);
```

To set the timeout a bit higher, so the client has 30 seconds time to accept the certificate (if self signged) and do all the tls stuff.
After this is finished I really need to set the timeout back to 1000 microseconds.
The TLS-Negotation worked after this change, but I lost my timeout settings.

This is my problem. The **stream_set_timeout** call after **stream_socket_enable_crypto** does not work.

I have a log entry

```
echo "AFTER PROCESS MESSAGE QUEUE\n";
$buffer = fread($sock, 4096);
echo "AFTER SOCKET READ\n";
```

The message **AFTER PROCESS MESSAGE QUEUE** is printed but the **AFTER SOCKET READ** is not printed out and it does not matter how long I wait.

Does anybody has a glue how I can set the stream read timeout back to 1000 microseconds?

**For your info:**
A solution where I should set stream_set_blocking to false is currently **NOT** wanted.
For now I only want a blocking solution. 
If there is REALLY no other solution as to use non-blocking, then of course I want to know :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. `stream_select` helped me solve the problem:

```
$buffer='';
$select=array('con1'=>$socket);
$timeout_sec=1;
if(stream_select($select, $null, $null, $timeout_sec)){
    $buffer = fread($socket, $size);
}
```

Comment: While it is always good to show code, you should also describe *why* the shown code solves the problem as presented in the question. Please [edit] your answer to add a description.