# PHP stream_socket_enable_crypto hangs indefinitely. Anyway to fix?

Tags: php, sockets, starttls

I have a PHP script that I use to send emails to my newsletter list in one of my sites.

The script uses STARTTLS for encrypted connections, using the following line to establish the SSL handshake:

```php
stream_set_timeout($s, 35, 0);                                  
if(false == stream_socket_enable_crypto($s, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT)){
    $msg = "452 failed on tls connection";
} else {
    $in_tls = true;
}
```

The socket $s is set to blocking and is already connected to the remote server after issuing a STARTTLS command and ready to start TLS handshake at this stage.  As you can see, I am using stream_set_timeout before the handshake.  According to the PHP docs it *should* abort the handshake after X seconds, but it doesn't seem to affect it.

Now this code works *most* of the time, but I sometimes run into servers where the TLS handshake would just block indefinitely, causing the script to hang.

I've tried looking into non-blocking solutions, but none of them worked for my PHP version (I use v5.1.6).

The only other option is to somehow monitor this line for timeout (I'm not sure if that's possible), or to somehow transfer the socket handle to another process I can run with a timeout control method.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set a timeout on the stream, see [php manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) for `stream_set_timeout($s)`

> When the stream times out, the 'timed_out' key of the array returned
>   by stream_get_meta_data() is set to TRUE, although no error/warning is
>   generated.

Also found this on PHP manual

> In case anyone is puzzled, stream_set_timeout DOES NOT work for
>   sockets created with socket_create or socket_accept. Use
>   socket_set_option instead.

```
Instead of:
<?php
stream_set_timeout($socket,$sec,$usec);
?>

Use:
<?php
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec'=>$sec, 'usec'=>$usec));
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec'=>$sec, 'usec'=>$usec));
?>
```

Update: This allowed the OP to move past the issue
`ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1);`

Comment: I have tried this.  It doesn't realy seem to affect the stream_socket_enable_crypto line in case the handshake is timed out.  I'll modify my question and show the entire code

Comment: @MikiBerkovich maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048428/stream-socket-enable-crypto-disables-stream-set-timeout

Comment: You can also try passing `session_stream` params to `stream_socket_enable_crypto`. In the example on php docs they pass an int of 30. `stream_socket_client("tcp://myproto.example.com:31337", $errno, $errstr, 30);`

Comment: Nothing seems to affect stream_socket_enable_crypto.  I have even tried setting a timeout of complete 0 .  it just seems to ignore any setting on the socket.

Comment: 0 will normally mean it will never timeout. have you tried passing say 2 as last param in stream_socket_client?
`stream_socket_client($s, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, stream_context_create($options));`

Comment: Yes I have a timeout of 3 in stream_socket_client.   However, On one server (which is actually the server where I had the timeout occuring) I have IP rotation between stream_socket_client (local bind) and fsockopen (remote bind).   So there, I use the stream_socket_enable_crypto on the fsockopen'ed socket.   Could this be the problem?

Comment: it could be that its not binding to the correct current stream/context. But I still struggle to see why PHP would not enforce the timeout period. Maybe try and use another method or try without the IP rotation?

Comment: Ok.  I have done multiply tests.  Using stream_socket_client using both STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT and STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT.  It seems that stream_socket_enable_crypto just completely ignores any settings on timeout on the stream socket.   Very wierd.  Could this be a bug in PHP?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? also have you set `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1);` ? 
Maybe also worth using/checking out `feof` http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php
Additionally, PHP manual for steam_socket_client has some good info http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php

Comment: I use version 5.1.6 .   I have now tried ini_set('default_socket_timeout') and it seems to be working!   I'll give this approach a try.   Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great to hear! I have read about bugs in older versions of php. If you want to refrain from setting globally I suggest you update to min of 5.6 and try suggestions